# Handle when a trigger is executed without having to indicate the columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers, eventtrigger

Currently I have two triggers on the same table for the UPDATE action, one of them is responsible for the implementation of existing audit fields in the table. The other is responsible for checking the updated records to perform validation. The problem is that although the Trigger prioritize verification, above the audit as the two run the upgrade option comes into a small "loop" and makes perform the checks 2 times instead of one.
I know that if I point to clause IF (UPDATE (Camp1)) BEGIN .... It will allow me to run only when certain fields are modified, but is there any other way?

Comment: In general, I'd avoid multiple triggers for the same action. But https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186762(SQL.90).aspx

Comment: Would it be possible to combine your 2 into one?  Multiple update triggers for the same action, as @MitchWheat stated is not wise.

Comment: Thank´s for answering.
@MitchWheat  the problem I have is that although instructed the order triggers each other because it is an update of the table and then calls the two triggers. Currently as was by solving is that only one of the trigger has a column that is affected and the remaining columns in another. So I wondering if it was possible to perform the action indicated above. For as comments @ MisterPositive stated is not wise.